# Javascript does not sum numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, sum

I'm not good using javascript/jquery so this is a dumb question!
I coded this

```
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mazzodifiori.it/fiori/P15-Ficus.jpg"><img src="http://www.mazzodifiori.it/fiori/P15-Ficus.jpg" width=50 height=50 /></a>
        <br><input name="p1" value="p1" prezzo="5" type="checkbox" />
        <br><label>Pianta &euro;</label><span class="price">5</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mazzodifiori.it/fiori/P15-Ficus.jpg"><img src="http://www.mazzodifiori.it/fiori/P15-Ficus.jpg" width=50 height=50 /></a>
        <br><input name="p2" value="p2" prezzo="3" type="checkbox" />
        <br><label>Pianta &euro;</label><span class="price">3</span>
    </li>

var checkValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('prezzo');
}).get();

for(var i=0;i<checkValues.length;i++) {
    var tot = tot + checkValues[i];
    alert(tot);
}
```

In this way checkvalues contains array of numbers. So checking that 2 checkbox for example, on the browser appear 2 alert:

```
undefined5
```

and

```
undefined53
```

like if javascript is concatenating numbers like they would be strings!

how can i solve this?

Comment: `var tot = tot + checkValues[i];` - the `tot` on right hand side is not initialized . hence the result. Put the declaration outside the loop `var tot=0;`

Comment: Why do you think `checkValues` contains an array of numbers? Have you read the documentation for `.attr()`? It always returns a string (or `undefined`).

Comment: watch this exception Cannot read property 'map' of null, seems the problem is that map function recieves null or undefined values from checkboxes

Comment: You should change this `for(var i=0;i<checkValues.length;i++) { var tot = tot + checkValues[i]; 
alert(tot); 
}`   
to this: `var i,tot=0; 
for(i=0;i<checkValues.length;i++) { 
tot = tot + +checkValues[i]; 
alert(tot); 
}`.
Javascript doesn't have block scope - so it's less confusing if you write it outside of the `for` block. Also, you should initialize `tot` to zero because in the first iteration `tot`'s value is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
var tot = 0;
for(var i=0;i<checkValues.length;i++) {
    tot = tot + parseInt(checkValues[i]);
    alert(tot);
}
```

Comment: I fix it following your "tot = tot + parseInt(checkValues[i]);" and the advice that gave me raligan!

I'm very happy I fixed my problem!! THANK YOU :DDD

PS=I tried to use parseInt but it didn't function... maybe I was doing it wrong!

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone Alternatively, you could use `for(var i=0, tot=0;i<checkValues.length;i++) {`

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

`var tot = tot + checkValues[i];`

to this:

`var tot = tot + +checkValues[i];`

**OR**

change this:
`return $(this).attr('prezzo');`

to this:

`return +$(this).attr('prezzo');`

This will coerce the string to a number

Answer (score 1):

You keep reinitializing tot (which isn't strictly speaking a problem in JS, but it's bad form), plus you're initializing it to undefined initially, since you're defining it as itself.  Initialize it to 0 before the loop.

Comment: While this fixes the `undefined` problem, it will still do string concatentation, not addition

Comment: it's anyway an error from me. Thank you, I'm fixing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a duck typed (loosely typed) language. If it thinks they're strings, it'll concat them. Try forcing them into the data type you need. If they're integers, use parseInt(varName) + parseInt(varName2).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: If on of the variables is "undefined," parseInt won't be able to parse it because undefined is not a number. Check to see if your values are numbers by using IsNaN(var1) before parsing.